# JWPlayer SWF Stopping error

Tags: javascript, flash, jwplayer

I am having an issue with my JWPlayer and getting the player to stop. The player is in a modal and I would like the video to stop playing once I close out of the video. I am doing that via javascript as shown here

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('close').addEventListener('click', function() {
        jwplayer('jwcontent').stop();
    });
}
```

I know that function is working because if I use a console.log there it does execute when I click the close button on the modal.

The JWPlayer is working great other then that, it is jwplayer.version="5.7.1896". I've taken a look at the JWPlayer Javascript API but I can not get this to work. We initialize the JWPlayer like this:

```
jwplayer("jwcontent").setup({flashplayer:"http://urlhere/jwplayer/player.swf",.....});
```

I am wondering if it is because they are using a flashplayer. As I said, the video and playlist works but I cannot get the stop method to work.

Comment: You're using a VERY obsolete, unsupported version of JW Player. I'd suggest moving to JW 6.11, which has a very different embedding method, before trying to debug any further.

Comment: Actually I think MisterNeutron was correct. I updated to JWPlayer 6.11 and the player is stopping now. Thank you for your advice

Comment: Glad that took care of it!